# Can't get rid of red inbox flag

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I logged in today, the little red inbox flag was lit up red with the number 1.  So I clicked on it, and then clicked on the linked message, but whenever I log in again it still comes up red.

I have tried clicking on all the messages visible one at a time but that hasn't done any good.

Is there any way to mark "all messages read" like there is in a typical email program?  Or some other way for me to get rid of the red flag?

Comment: Same thing is happening to me. That's definitely a bug.

Comment: If you click on the inbox icon twice (without clicking any items on the inbox list), the red indicator goes away. But it comes back as soon as you move to another page on the site or refresh the current one. It seems to be happening across all of SE, including on SO.

Comment: Same here as well as the points earned ( + # in green)

Comment: Same thing that Ricardo is describing.

Comment: This was already brought up on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238155/226495) and [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268957/2467198). (Just FYI.)

Comment: Seems to be fixed!

Comment: @placeholder Agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had problems with a datacenter test that left our caching layer in a partially broken state.

All issues should now be resolved.

See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268957/topbar-notifications-dont-go-away